# Launch make in vim without leaving vim

Tags: vim, makefile

":make" is useful in vim for comping the program get the program with copen, but when you 
 launch make, the screen will return back to shell and wait until the make finish, is there 
 any way I can use to get rid of it? I just want to launch make, and still able to brower 
 my code, when the make finish, I can use copen to check the result.

Comment: I believe vim is single threaded so there is no way to make `:make` run without waiting for it to finish. You might be able to run it in the background but then copen won't contain the error results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have to use `:make` to use `:copen`.  From the command line (bash syntax shown here):

```
make .... > error.txt 2>&1
```

Then from within vim:

```
:cf error.txt
```

Comment: Great! I can create a map for it

Answer (score 0):

You may want to actually check out tpope's [dispatch plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-dispatch). There is [a short video](http://vimeo.com/tpope/vim-dispatch-teaser) that gives you an idea of what it does, which is basically to run an arbitrary command in the background and return the results (ie, :make results) w/o messing with your workflow. Highly recommended.